# How do I read a text file into an array of array (each sub-array being a row in the text file?)

Tags: ruby, arrays, file, split

so I'm pretty much a n00b at Ruby, and I've put together a code to solve a MinCut problem (for an assignment, yes - that part of the code I've put together and tested), and I can't figure out how to read a file and put it into an array of arrays. I have a text file to read, with columns of varying length as below

> 1 37  79  164
>
> 2 123 134
>
> 3        48      123     134   109

and I'd like to read it into a 2D array, where each line and columnn is split, with each line going into one array. So the resulting array for the above example would be :

```
[[1, 37, 79, 164], [2, 123, 134], [3, 48, 123, 134, 109]]
```

My code to read the text file is below:

```
def read_array(file, count)
  int_array = []
  File.foreach(file) do |f|
    counter = 0
    while (l = f.gets and counter < count ) do
      temp_array = []
      temp_array << l.to_i.split(" ")
      int_array << temp_array
      counter = counter + 1
    end

  end
  return int_array
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Also, if it helps, the error I'm currently getting is "block in read_array': private method 'gets' called for # "

I've tried a few things, and have gotten different error messages though...

Answer (score 24):

```
File.readlines('test.txt').map do |line|
  line.split.map(&:to_i)
end
```

**Explanation**

`readlines` reads the whole file and splits it by newlines. It looks like this:

```
["1 37 79 164\n", "2 123 134\n", "3 48 123 134 109"]
```

Now we iterate over the lines (using `map`) and split each line into its number parts (`split`)

```
[["1", "37", "79", "164"], ["2", "123", "134"], ["3", "48", "123", "134", "109"]]
```

The items are still strings, so the inner `map` converts them to integers (`to_i`).

```
[[1, 37, 79, 164], [2, 123, 134], [3, 48, 123, 134, 109]]
```

Comment: What is the `&:` for?

Comment: `.map(&:to_i)` is equivalent to `.map { |s| s.to_i }`. More specifically, the `&` calls `to_proc` on the symbol. See: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc

Answer (score 11):

Ruby's got you covered with just a few lines:

**tmp.txt**

```
1 2 3
10 20 30 45
4 2
```

**Ruby code**

```
a = []
File.open('tmp.txt') do |f|
  f.lines.each do |line|
    a << line.split.map(&:to_i)
  end
end

puts a.inspect
# => [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30, 45], [4, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's why I'm loving ruby, every time I'm having trouble with something the answer turns out to be much easier than previously thought

Answer (score 2):

The error in your code occurs because you are calling the method `gets` on the object `f`, which is a `String`, not a `File` as you would expected (check [the documentation for `IO#foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) for more informations).

Instead of fixing your code I suggest you to rewrite it in a simpler and more Rubyish style, I'd write it like this:

```
def read_array(file_path)
  File.foreach(file_path).with_object([]) do |line, result|
    result << line.split.map(&:to_i)
  end
end
```

Given this `file.txt`:

```
1 37 79 164
2 123 134
3 48 123 134 109
```

It produce this output:

```
read_array('file.txt')
# => [[1, 37, 79, 164], [2, 123, 134], [3, 48, 123, 134, 109]]
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the error he got. The rest of us forgot that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
array_line = []  

if File.exist? 'test.txt'
  File.foreach( 'test.txt' ) do |line|
      array_line.push line
  end
end
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_array(file)
  int_array = []

  File.open(file, "r").each_line { |line| int_array << line.split(' ').map {|c| c.to_i} }

  int_array
end
```